# First Blackjack game in C

Tags: c, beginner, game, playing-cards

This is my first real program, though it has gone through a few major revisions. Anyhow, I am sure that there is a lot I could have done better, cleaner or safer.

Can anyone see anything I really need to work on or fix?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <allegro.h>

struct cards
{
    int card_value[10];
    char card_name[10];
    char card_suit[10];
    int card_tally;
    BITMAP *card_pic[10];
};

struct cards hand[2];
short decks=1;
short cards_used[14]= {0};
int player_cash = 500;


void endgame()
{
    if (player_cash < 1)
        alert("You lost it all big guy! Better luck next time!", NULL, NULL, "&Ok", NULL, 'o', 'k');

    else if (player_cash < 501)
        alert("Game Over: Not enough cards to continue",
              "In the end, you didn't win a dime but at least",
              "you still have the shirt on your back",
              "&Ok", NULL, 'o', 'k');

    else
    {
        char cash[100];
        snprintf(cash, sizeof(cash), "You are leaving with $%d", player_cash);
        alert("Amazing! You beat the house!", cash, NULL, "&Ok", NULL, 'o', 'k');
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


void tally (int a)
{
    int x=0, y=0;
    for (x=0; x<10; x++)
    {
        y = y + hand[a].card_value[x];
    }
    hand[a].card_tally = y;
}

void check_for_ace (int a)
{
    int x;
    for (x=0; x<10; x++)
    {   if (hand[a].card_name[x] =='A')
        {
            int y;
            int z = 10;
            for (y=0; y<10; y++)
                z = z + hand[a].card_value[y];
            if (z < 22)
                hand[a].card_value[x]=11;
            else
                hand[a].card_value[x]=1;
        }
    }
}

void draw_card (int a)
{
    short z = 1 + rand () % 13;
    short x=0;
    short safe_guard=0;
    short y= 1 + rand () % 4;
    char card_suit = 'd';

    while (hand[a].card_value[x] !=  0)
        x++;

    while ((cards_used[z] > (decks * 4)) && (safe_guard < 50))
    {
        z = 1 + rand () % 13;
        safe_guard++;
    }

    if (safe_guard > 49)
        endgame();

    cards_used[z] = cards_used[z] + 1;
    safe_guard=0;

    /*Now Assign Values and Names to the Cards*/

    if ((z > 1) && (z < 10))
    {
        hand[a].card_value[x]=z;
        hand[a].card_name[x]=((char) '0' + z);
    }
    else if (z == 10)
    {
        hand[a].card_value[x]=z;
        hand[a].card_name[x]='T';
    }
    else if (z == 11)
    {
        hand[a].card_value[x]=10;
        hand[a].card_name[x]='J';
    }
    else if (z == 12)
    {
        hand[a].card_value[x]=10;
        hand[a].card_name[x]='Q';
    }
    else if (z == 13)
    {
        hand[a].card_value[x]=10;
        hand[a].card_name[x]='K';
    }
    else if (z == 1)
    {
        /*Function 'check_for_ace' deals with this more properly*/
        hand[a].card_value[x]=1;
        hand[a].card_name[x]='A';
    }

    /*Assign Suits Randomly*/
    if (y == 1)
        card_suit='c';
    if (y == 2)
        card_suit='d';
    if (y == 3)
        card_suit='h';
    if (y == 4)
        card_suit='s';

    check_for_ace(a);

    /*Link the Picture*/
    char pic[20];
    snprintf(pic, sizeof(pic), "card/%c%c.bmp", hand[a].card_name[x], card_suit);
    hand[a].card_pic[x]=load_bmp(pic, NULL);

    tally(a);
}

void display_hands ()
{
    int x;
    int y=10;

    clear_bitmap(screen);

    /*Dealer hand*/
    for (x=0; hand[0].card_name[x]!=0; x++)
    {
        blit(hand[0].card_pic[x], screen, 0,0,y,10,73,97);
        y=y+75;
    }

    /*Player Hand, displayed on bottom of screen*/
    y=10;

    for (x=0; hand[1].card_name[x]!=0; x++)
    {
        blit(hand[1].card_pic[x], screen, 0,0,y,300,73,97);
        y=y+75;
    }

    textprintf_ex(screen, font, 335, 2, makecol(0, 0, 0), makecol(248, 248, 230), "         ");
    textprintf_ex(screen, font, 335, 10, makecol(0, 0, 0), makecol(248, 248, 230), "  Cash   ");
    textprintf_ex(screen, font, 335, 18, makecol(0, 0, 0), makecol(248, 248, 230), "   %d    ", player_cash);
    textprintf_ex(screen, font, 335, 26, makecol(0, 0, 0), makecol(248, 248, 230), "         ");
}




void dealer_turn()
{
    while (hand[0].card_tally < 17)
    {
        draw_card(0);
        display_hands();
    }
    if (hand[0].card_tally > 21)
    {
        hand[0].card_tally = 0;
        alert("Dealer Busts!", NULL, NULL, "&Ok", NULL, 'o', 'k');
    }
}


void player_turn()
{
    int action=1;

    while (action != 2 && hand[1].card_tally < 21)
    {
        action=alert("What will you do?", NULL, NULL, "&Hit", "&Stand", 'h', 's');
        if (action == 1)
            draw_card(1);
        display_hands();
        tally(1);
    }

    if (hand[1].card_tally > 21)
        alert("Player Busts!", NULL, NULL, "&Ok", NULL, 'o', 'k');

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    allegro_init();
    install_keyboard();
    install_mouse();
    set_color_depth(16);
    set_gfx_mode(GFX_AUTODETECT_WINDOWED, 400,400,0,0);

    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;
    if (argv[0])
        decks = atoi (argv[0]);


    srand(time(NULL));


    int x=0;
    while (x != -1)
    {
        display_hands();
        int bet = 50;
        int alert_val = alert3("Please place your bet", NULL, NULL, "&50", "&100", "15&0", '5', '1', '0');
        bet = alert_val * 50;
        player_cash=player_cash - bet;
        display_hands();
        draw_card(0);
        draw_card(1);
        draw_card(1);
        display_hands();
        player_turn();
        if (hand[1].card_tally < 22)
        {
            dealer_turn();
            display_hands();
        }
        if ((hand[0].card_tally > hand[1].card_tally) || (hand[0].card_tally == hand[1].card_tally
                || hand[1].card_tally > 21))
        {
            alert("Dealer wins!", NULL, NULL, "&Ok", NULL, 'o', 'k');
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Player wins!", NULL, NULL, "&Ok", NULL, 'o', 'k');
            player_cash = player_cash + (bet * 2);
            display_hands();
        }


        if (player_cash < 1)
            endgame();
        int i;
        for (i=0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for (x=0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                hand[i].card_name[x] = 0;
                hand[i].card_suit[x] = 0;
                hand[i].card_value[x] = 0;
            }
            hand[i].card_tally = 0;
        }

        if (alert("Continue or Quit?", NULL, NULL, "&Continue", "&Quit", 'c', 'q') == 2)
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }


    int loop=0;
    for (loop=0; loop < 11; loop++)
    {
        destroy_bitmap(hand[0].card_pic[loop]);
        destroy_bitmap(hand[1].card_pic[loop]);
    }



    return 0;
}
END_OF_MAIN();
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Code Review. Questions without code in them are considered off topic, so you'll need to inline the link. If you're having trouble indenting so it's formatted as code, just paste in the code, select it all, and hit Control + K.

Comment: Wow, I did not realize that would work. I always thought I had to indent it line by line.

Comment: Small thing that I see as of right now, all your vars and functions are_like_that BUT endgame! You should put it as end_game to keep up consistency!

Answer (score 10):

I have some comments, some of which are quite pedantic.

- Avoid hard-coded constants (eg 10, 'c, 'd', 'A' etc) - use defines or const
- Inconsistent spacing around `=` etc
- Use of globals is undesirable unless necessary - here it is mostly not, really. And if you must use globals in a file, make them static unless they really **must** be shared between files.  And that is rare.
- Make local functions static wherever possible
- Add an explicit `void` in empty function parameter lists
- Add braces on single statement:

  ```
  if (condition) {
      statement;
  }
  ```
- Variable names x,y,z etc are undescriptive and unhelpful.  Use of very short
  names is not necessarily bad, but you should only use such names where it is
  obvious what they relate to.  In this code it hinders understanding (mine anyway)
- use of `short` rather than `int` is generally pointless
- I would prefer to see the 'hand' passed around as a pointer to struct (const if possible) rather than a hand number `a`
- `tally` is more useful if it just sums the content of the `card_value` array
  and returns the sum without writing to `card_tally`.  Note that `check_for_ace` contains a loop that is much the same as (and therefore could use) `tally`

### In `draw_card`:

- This loop should be a function.  Also there is no error check

  ```
  while (hand[a].card_value[x] !=  0)
      x++;
  ```
- The subsequent loop generates a random card that hasn't already been 
  used up but there should be a `cards_used` array for each suit. I
  know your deck*4 is supposed to handle that, but does it prevent the same card (4 of hearts, say) being used 4 times (with one deck)?  You might perhaps use
  one array of 52 entries covering all suits.  I'd put the loop in a
  function too.
- a switch might be better than many if/else

### In `display_hands`

- there are two almost identical loops - extract them into a function

### In `main`

- `main` is too big
- Did you chop out some argument handling in `main`? What you have looks odd.
- The reset loop in `main` should also be extracted into a separate function
- Variable `loop` in the bitmap-destroy loop is badly named
- `END_OF_MAIN` - what is this? - remove it anyway.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I did remove some argument handling code from the main. I originally had an option to set a starting value to the player_cash variable. END_OF_MAIN is required by the Allegro 4 library according to some of what I've read.

Comment: In addition to the above, another thing to consider is to declare loop iterators inside the loop, that's more common practice. That is: `for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)`. (Since you already have a C compiler that allows declaration of variables anywhere, it will also allow this.)

Answer (score 7):

Here are a few things I notice from skimming through your code:

Pros:

- Nice and clean style, lines are short enough to ease reading
- Picked good names for functions

Cons:

- The use of one-letter variable. They are not descriptive. For example, `void tally (int a)`
   does not say what a is

Suggestions:

- Use named constants such as HEART, CLUB, ... to help code readability and maintainability.
- Code consistency: I see places where you surround equal sign with space (e.g. `x = 0`) and places where you don't (e.g. `x=0`). You should be more consistent.
- Refactor of `display_hands()`: in this function, you have the same code repeated twice, once for the dealer and once for the player. There is opportunity to refactor the code by pulling the common block into a separate function.